# How to handle Nullable<T> types returned from stored proc?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, nullable, cpu-usage, memory-profiling

I am looking for some suggestion over best practice (considering Memory and CPU time) to handle `Nullable<T>` fields returned from a stored procedure on using Linq2Sql.

Please consider the following scenario and limitations:

1. I want to avoid using fieldValue.HasValue check everywhere in the code. Thus, I need to replace all `Nullable<T>` with normal properties (esp DateTime, Double, Int) with some default value.
2. I am expecting to read ~1million objects with ~20 fields of Nullable type.
3. Memory and CPU usage is an important consideration.
4. The requirement is to get result from stored proc in an object (not DataRow), and thus using Linq2Sql.

Please share your opinion or experience over handling a similar situation.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the field is null?

Comment: Is LINQ to SQL a hard core requirement? The reason I'm asking is because there is overhead and might be best do execute store procedures or queries for performance / memory reasons.

Comment: "I need to replace all ... with some default value." - with that restriction in place you're essentially changing the meaning of the data under those circumstances where the default value chosen is actual data. If you're data never contains those default values as valid values (which is always arguable), why do you use `Nullable<T>` (or a nullable column I assume) in the first place?

Comment: @Christian K: it's not changing the definition of data. Stored Proc returns whatever is there in table (including null). The business rests at client side, and thus business decision about default value is with client (C#).

Comment: Won't replacing `null` with some default value mean that you will have to check for that default value instead of checking for `null`? This looks like it won't add any benefit to me.

Comment: @msarchet: For null values, I will replace with business default values (not null).

Comment: @svick: No, I won't need to check for the business default values per field. The object will be written in a report, and it is valid to let go a business default value in report, without any further check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Solution:

- Don't allow SQL to return NULL Values.
- The easiest way to do this is to not allow the columns themselves to be null, but if that isn't a possibility then you can do an ISNULL(field, defaultvalue) in the query that you are using to return the data.

Next Best Solution:

- Overwrite the LINQToSQL objects get call to check if the object HasValue and then if not set it to the `default(type)` value for the field.

There is no way to not check every value.

Answer (score 1):

You can write extension methods such as:

```
public static string SafeGetString(this SqlDataReader _Reader, int _ColIndex)
{
    if (_Reader.IsDBNull(_ColIndex))
        return null; //Default value
    else
        return _Reader.GetString(_ColIndex);
}
```

For each type used (there are actually not so many), set the default value to something other than `null` if you want to insert the data into non-nullable types.

Comment: Agree. But this will be a performance hit! Consider iterating over 1M rows, with 20 properties (20M) calls to this method with null check!!!

Comment: @Amby the only way to not check each value is to not allow SQL to return a null.

Answer (score 0):

A hardcore option is to coalesce the values at their source. You'll guarantee that nulls will stay away from the data readers.

But as performance seems to be a big concern, I'd suggest that you measure different options to make an informed decision before compromising the sanity of your code (over-optimizing) or the sanity of your runtime (abusing memory or cpu).

As a side note, fetching millions of rows from a database most certainly will cause sensible impact somewhere. You'll usually have to decide where/when it will hurt less!